# views with a SOAP back end

Tags: 7, views

views3 supports plugable backends rather than a RDBMS, there are backends for solr, sparql, mongodb.

Is there such a plug in to enable views to be a front end for a SOAP api? I have found a number of modules to do with services, soap, etc. But nothing which would clearly fill this role.

Comment: *a SOAP api* is very generic: SOAP is a standard that merely describes the communication, but not the available methods nor the datastruture. I expect there is not a common *SOAP* backend available that will work for you without developing the resources, methods and mappers for **your** SOAP implemenentation.

Comment: I don't know one, too. This might be helpful to provide this as a generic solution as a gsoc project. Technological it should work but you need to provide a way to explain views which kind of backends are there. Perhaps instead of writing a soap query backend it might make sense to use services in general. But this isn't that easy.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Drupal 7/Views 3, but with Views 2 I used the Services module several times to expose content via Views, e.g. Services + SOAP Server + Views to make a bespoke Drupal-powered SOAP API. Perhaps that's not what you're after? SOAP Server would need porting anyway, but perhaps you could experiment with Views 3 and Services 3 and if it works ok with XML-RPC then consider helping port SOAP Server. It probably wouldn't take much work.

Answer (score 0):

We have done this internally, but we coded it all ourselves. It is not tricky to do, but will take time.

You need to get a handle on how Views are built. Because you can use plugins to define how datasources, fields, filters, and arguments are handled, you can integrate with views really nicely.

Here are some good resources:

http://views.doc.logrus.com/

http://blue.live4all.co.il/~mooffie/tmp/views_illustrated/views_life.html